# Framework code "can't resolve symbols" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to debug through library code in Android Studio. But it shows unresolved symbols, i.e., red lines at lots of places.

[image]

My app `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kuldeep.customview"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

My project `build.gradle` file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the code for TextView, which is an Android platform class and not part of your app.  Platform classes can refer to other "package private" classes that are not part of the visible API for an app. Android studio provides for you the ability to view platform source code like this so you can see how it works, but you can't make changes to it and you don't get access to all the actual compiled classes in the SDK.

The short story is that is regular and expected.  If you were seeing this for *your own app code* (not platform classes or add-on libraries) then you'd have something to be concerned about.

Comment: `The short story is` - Is there also a longer story to this? I.e. is there any way to reduce these error messages or better yet to resolve them? As it is using the debugger is very hard when looking at Android source files since one can hardly see anything but (mostly false) error indicators in the outline...

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reasons:

1. Gradle not synced.
   Try syncing your gradle files using `Gradle Sync`.
2. SDK not updated.
   Make sure your SDK is updated and that you have all the extra packages that you need installed. You can do that using `SDK Manager`.